# Represent a company network infrastructure with UML?

Tags: uml

Is it possible to represent a company network infrastructure (router, firewall, switch but also real and virtual servers, VPN) with a UML diagram?

What about the component diagram or similar?
What about the deployment diagram or similar? I don't want to represent the deployment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this usefull link about this subject http://www.uml-diagrams.org/network-architecture-diagrams.html

or this answer [What's the best way to represent a networked connection in a UML class diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/705395/196526)

Answer (score 0):

UML is not primarily designed for network infrastructure diagrams. If you really need to, you could use the UML deployment diagram. Every network node is represented by a 3-dimensional box. Its stereotype specifies the kind of node, e.g. «switch» or «router». If you prefer to use more diverse symbols, UML allows you to define your own profile, where you can map each stereotype to a specific symbol. By using such a profile, you can use these symbols instead of the boxes.